Convergence of a Fourier Series at a Point
I'm trying to understand the pointwise convergence of Fourier series, particularly for functions that have singularities or are otherwise difficult to analyze.
Define the function $f(x)$ as:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
|x|^{1/2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right) & \text{if } 0 < |x| \leq \pi \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Show that the Fourier series of $f(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ at every point $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.
My initial thought is to analyze the behavior of the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ and apply convergence tests for Fourier series, possibly involving the Dirichlet conditions or integration by parts. Could this be the right path?

Discontinuity at $0$?

This might be of some interest to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804929/fourier-series-of-piecewise-defined-function-and-convergence?rq=1
